# Android multiple crash alerts

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

If I throw an exception within my application it will crash as expected displaying the message " unfortunately has stopped ". However it seems weird that it displays this message then opens another activity and displays the message again. It basically iterates through all of my activites showing this message before the app restarts.

I throw a test exception by casting a `TextView` to a `LinearLayout`, here is the output:

```
01-28 12:04:36.270: E/AndroidRuntime(23772): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
01-28 12:04:36.270: E/AndroidRuntime(23772):    at com.iii.News.onCreate(News.java:16)
01-28 12:04:36.270: E/AndroidRuntime(23772):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-28 12:04:36.270: E/AndroidRuntime(23772):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-28 12:04:36.270: E/AndroidRuntime(23772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-28 12:04:36.270: E/AndroidRuntime(23772):    ... 11 more
01-28 12:04:42.706: D/dalvikvm(23873): newInstance failed: no <init>()
01-28 12:04:42.706: D/AndroidRuntime(23873): Shutting down VM
01-28 12:04:42.706: W/dalvikvm(23873): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ff3930)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iii/com.iii.Forums}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.iii.menu.TradingMenuFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.iii.menu.TradingMenuFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1760)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:200)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:20)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at com.iii.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:29)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at com.iii.Forums.onCreate(Forums.java:9)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    ... 11 more
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.iii.menu.TradingMenuFragment; no empty constructor
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873):    ... 20 more
01-28 12:04:57.442: D/dalvikvm(23901): newInstance failed: no <init>()
01-28 12:04:57.442: D/AndroidRuntime(23901): Shutting down VM
01-28 12:04:57.442: W/dalvikvm(23901): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ff3930)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iii/com.iii.Markets}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.iii.menu.TradingMenuFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.iii.menu.TradingMenuFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1760)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:200)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:20)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at com.iii.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:29)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at com.iii.Markets.onCreate(Markets.java:9)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    ... 11 more
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.iii.menu.TradingMenuFragment; no empty constructor
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: share your logcat report

Comment: Okay it looks like the issue is coming from the sliding menu library i am using.  https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

01-28 12:04:57.442: E/AndroidRuntime(23901):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1760)

when the app breaks it tries the restore the fragments state

Comment: sorry to waste your time i have fixed the issue all i needed to do was create a empty constructor for the fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, apparently you are trying to use a `TradingMenuFragment` but as you can see from the logcat, there is no empty constructor to it.

```
01-28 12:04:42.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23873): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
    can't instantiate class com.iii.menu.TradingMenuFragment; no empty constructor
```

fix that and all should be ok.